# Assembly input error

Tags: loops, assembly, input, scanf

I'm trying to read a number from input and then calculate it's factors(don't know if they are factors, for example 10's factors are 1,2,5,10). I believe that my calculation part is correct because when I calculate factors of value that was preset in the code it works. But when I try to input the value, I get wrong results.
I will post code that works with pre-set value 1000 (doesn't matter what you input, it calculates 1000's factors).

```
; ----------------------------------------------------
; LeiaTegurid.asm
; @brief    Leiab sisestatud numbri tegurid.
; @author   Eerik Muuli

; @date     27.01.2014
; ----------------------------------------------------
global  _main        ; make visible for linker
extern  _printf      ; link with printf
extern _scanf ; Kasutaja sisendi jaoks.
extern _atoi  ;string->int
; -------------------------------
section .const
  hello db `Tegur: %d \n\0`; 0 on stringi lõpp.
  otsitav dw 1000 
; -------------------------------  
section .data
s6num db `Sisesta arv: \0` ; Küsib sisendi.
vaste db "%s", 0 ; Sisend.
; -------------------------------
section .bss
inpt resb 1000 ; Reserveerib 1000 baiti.
; -------------------------------
section .text
_main:
push ebp  ;proloog
mov  ebp, esp

push s6num
call _printf ; Prindib: "Sisesta arv: "
add esp, 4

push inpt
push vaste ; Meie sisend
call _scanf
add esp, 8

push inpt
call _atoi ; String intiks.
add esp, 4

; mov ecx, eax
mov ebx,  dword[otsitav] ; Annab ebx-le kasutaja sisestatud väärtuse.
mov [esp-4], eax ; Annab esp-4-le kasutaja sis. väärtuse.

inc ebx ; Suurendab ebx-i. Vajalik tsükli jaoks.
;mov edx, dword[otsitav] ; Annab edx-le väärtuseks kasutaja valitud arvu.

.loop1: ; Tsükkel algab.
cmp ebx , 1 ; võrdleb, et tsüklist välja saada.
je .end ; hüppab lõppu.
dec ebx ; võtab eax-ilt ühe ära.
xor edx, edx ; Nullib jäägi ära.

mov eax, dword[otsitav] ; Annab eax-le otsitava väärtuse.
idiv  ebx ; Jagab eax-i(otsitava) hetke arvuga.
; mov ecx, eax ; Paneb vastsuse ecx-i.
; Jääk on edx-is.

cmp edx, 0; edx(jääk) ? 0
jg .loop1 ; Kui jääk > 0, siis läheb insta algusesse.
push ebx ; Printimiseks.
push hello ; Printimiseks.
call _printf ; Kutsub printimise välja.
add esp, 8 ; Tasakaalustab.
jmp .loop1 ; Hüppab tsükli algusesse.

.end: ; lõpp

mov  esp, ebp ;epiloog, taastame registrid
pop  ebp
ret
```

I will now also post the version that reads the input and doesn't work.
Note that the lines that I've changed in the new version are marked with ***

```
; ----------------------------------------------------
; LeiaTegurid.asm
; @brief    Leiab sisestatud numbri tegurid.
; @author   Eerik Muuli
; @date     27.01.2014
; ----------------------------------------------------
global  _main        ; make visible for linker
extern  _printf      ; link with printf
extern _scanf ; Kasutaja sisendi jaoks.
extern _atoi  ;string->int
; -------------------------------
section .const
  hello db `Tegur: %d \n\0`; 0 on stringi lõpp.
  otsitav dw 1000 
; -------------------------------  
section .data
s6num db `Sisesta arv: \0` ; Küsib sisendi.
vaste db "%s", 0 ; Sisend.
; -------------------------------
section .bss
inpt resb 1000 ; Reserveerib 1000 baiti.
; -------------------------------
section .text
_main:
push ebp  ;proloog
mov  ebp, esp

push s6num
call _printf ; Prindib: "Sisesta arv: "
add esp, 4

push inpt
push vaste ; Meie sisend
call _scanf
add esp, 8

push inpt
call _atoi ; String intiks.
add esp, 4

***mov ecx, eax***
***mov ebx,  ecx ; Annab ebx-le kasutaja sisestatud väärtuse.***
mov [esp-4], eax ; Annab esp-4-le kasutaja sis. väärtuse.

inc ebx ; Suurendab ebx-i. Vajalik tsükli jaoks.
;mov edx, dword[otsitav] ; Annab edx-le väärtuseks kasutaja valitud arvu.

.loop1: ; Tsükkel algab.
cmp ebx , 1 ; võrdleb, et tsüklist välja saada.
je .end ; hüppab lõppu.
dec ebx ; võtab eax-ilt ühe ära.
xor edx, edx ; Nullib jäägi ära.

***mov eax, ecx ; Annab eax-le otsitava väärtuse.***
idiv  ebx ; Jagab eax-i(otsitava) hetke arvuga.
; mov ecx, eax ; Paneb vastsuse ecx-i.
; Jääk on edx-is.

cmp edx, 0; edx(jääk) ? 0
jg .loop1 ; Kui jääk > 0, siis läheb insta algusesse.
push ebx ; Printimiseks.
push hello ; Printimiseks.
call _printf ; Kutsub printimise välja.
add esp, 8 ; Tasakaalustab.
jmp .loop1 ; Hüppab tsükli algusesse.

.end: ; lõpp

mov  esp, ebp ;epiloog, taastame registrid
pop  ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this line is wrong:

```
mov [esp-4], eax ; Annab esp-4-le kasutaja sis. väärtuse.
```

You have not created space on the stack for this variable nor do you use it anywhere else.  Since you never made room for it, it is screwing up your stack.  Part of the prologue should be:
`sub esp, 4` to create room for this variable.  Let's just use another register that will be saved across the `print` call - `esi`.

Another problem, is your are not exiting the program correctly.  You are linking against the C Library, and it does some "behind the scenes" stuff before your `_main` function is even called, so to properly exit, you need to call `exit`
Here us the cleaned up code so is is more readable.  Not sure what Assembler you are using (I am guessing NASM) and why you are declaring the C functions with an underscore (Maybe on Windows?)  I just redefined the names so it will Assemble and Link correctly on my Linux box.

Fixed code is between:

```
;~ *************

;~ *************
```

Code:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------
; LeiaTegurid.asm
; @brief    Leiab sisestatud numbri tegurid.
; @author   Eerik Muuli

; @date     27.01.2014
; ----------------------------------------------------
global  _main        ; make visible for linker
extern  printf      ; link with printf
extern scanf ; Kasutaja sisendi jaoks.
extern atoi  ;string->int
%define _printf printf
%define _scanf scanf
%define _atoi atoi
extern exit

section .const
  hello db `Tegur: %d \n\0`; 0 on stringi lõpp.
  ;~ otsitav dw 10  
; -------------------------------  
section .data
s6num db `Sisesta arv: \0` ; Küsib sisendi.
vaste db "%s", 0 ; Sisend.
; -------------------------------
section .bss
inpt resb 1000 ; Reserveerib 1000 baiti.
; -------------------------------
section .text
_main:
    push    ebp  ;proloog
    mov     ebp, esp

    push    s6num
    call    _printf ; Prindib: "Sisesta arv: "
    add     esp, 4

    push    inpt
    push    vaste ; Meie sisend
    call    _scanf
    add     esp, 8

    push    inpt
    call    _atoi ; String intiks.
    add     esp, 4

    mov     ebx,  eax ;dword[otsitav] ; Annab ebx-le kasutaja sisestatud väärtuse.
    ;~ *************
    mov     esi, eax  ; Annab esp-4-le kasutaja sis. väärtuse.
    ;~ *************

    inc     ebx ; Suurendab ebx-i. Vajalik tsükli jaoks.

.loop1: ; Tsükkel algab.
    cmp     ebx , 1 ; võrdleb, et tsüklist välja saada.
    je      .end ; hüppab lõppu.
    dec     ebx ; võtab eax-ilt ühe ära.
    xor     edx, edx ; Nullib jäägi ära.

    ;~ *************
    mov     eax, esi ;dword[esp-4] ; *****dword[otsitav] ; Annab eax-le otsitava väärtuse.
    ;~ *************
    idiv    ebx ; Jagab eax-i(otsitava) hetke arvuga.

    cmp     edx, 0; edx(jääk) ? 0
    jg      .loop1 ; Kui jääk > 0, siis läheb insta algusesse.
    push    ebx ; Printimiseks.
    push    hello ; Printimiseks.
    call    _printf ; Kutsub printimise välja.
    add     esp, 8 ; Tasakaalustab.
    jmp     .loop1 ; Hüppab tsükli algusesse.

.end: ; lõpp

    mov     esp, ebp ;epiloog, taastame registrid
    pop     ebp

    ;~ *************
    push 0
    call exit
    ;~ *************
```